# How to get wall plugs out

Tags: bathroom, drywall

Anyone know how to get a super old wall plug out? My husband and I are redoing our house we just bought and have multiple all over our bathroom. The house was built in 1958 so I don’t know if that makes a difference in what kind of wall plugs were used. I looked up how to do it. Did it the way it shows (by screwing in a screw and grabbing it with pliers to pull out) and it took a huge chunk of the wall with it because it has a really big metal back behind the wall. I tried to add a picture but it’s not allowing me to.

Comment: I do hope you are not talking about electrical outlets.

Comment: sounds concerning...  no way to answer this without pictures

Comment: Can you post a photo? I'm still trying to figure out if we're talking about some sort of mounting fixing, or about electrical receptacles(!!!!!)

Comment: If it is a receptacle after you turn the power off. Remove the face plate. Then there are 2 screws one at top and bottom, remove those. Next where the screws went in there may be a small ear or circle to the left and right above the screw. Use a box cutter and cut around this metal piece, all the years of paint and or wall paper get put over the “yoke strap” and it will tear the wall if not cut. Then pry up the thin metal may be stuck because of paint but they break loose with a little force. If you don’t cut the paint can peal quite a chunk up look at a new receptacle or switch for the shape.

Comment: There are a half dozen different styles of wall anchors.  The technique used depends on the specific anchor design.

Comment: If it's a wall plug with a big back could just hammer it into the wall to fall down the back, leaving a small hole

Comment: Upload your pics to imgur.com and post the `share` links here in a comment. Someone will embed them for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing  hollow wall anchors. Molly screw is a common brand name that has come to be reference for almost any hollow wall anchor. I think you have half the removal process. You need to install a screw then gently tap it with a hammer. This will straighten out the insert allowing it to come out thru a hole slightly larger than the original.

Comment: You'd do well to find an anchor that hasn't been used. Then you can see how it might work in reverse. And, be able to work out what depth the screw needs to be knocked in.